# Facebook open graph predefiened games.match object usage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

I am trying to publish a story regarding winning events of my canvas game application users (Using Facebook predefined "common type" - [meta property="og:type" content="games.match"] object type).

Do I have to create a dedicated games.match "self-hosted object" html file for each game that took place in my application and for which I want to publish such a story? This doesn't make sense to me. The "games.match" object type REQUIRES me to supply at least one value of property type "games:players" - this implies that the user-ids relevant to the story are specific to the relevant games.match object and that they should be supplied - prior - to scraping that self-hosted object...

In addition, I made several attempts with such stories but could not see where Facbook makes use of the supplied user-ids - the relevant users' properties do not show in any of the stories, and attempts to use these properties when defining a story sentence (the Facebook-generated story generic header title - "UsernameX won ...") by using the game/match properties (i.e {game.title} / {match.players}) results in DEFAULT FORMATT of facebook-generated story sentence. Do I miss something or does Facebook use this information for other "back-stage" (statistics related) operations that it takes?